# how to get values from two content types using one entity reference

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 and have 3 content types -

1. Product
2. Purchase
3. Sales

In **sales** content type, I'm using entity reference I want to fetch and display "product name" from **Product** content type and "MRP" from **Purchase** content type. How can I achieve this by configuration?

Comment: All 3 content types are related with Entity Reference?

Comment: Is entity reference field in `Sales` referring to both other content types? Are you using separate entity reference field(s) to refer other content type(s)? How you are going to display, using views?

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 Content types need to be interrelated then it makes sense to use the *same* Entity Reference Field to connect them (two CTs both use the same Field to reference the third CT).

But this isn't a requirement, it just makes some things easier if using Views to display information from one CT node on related CT nodes. While this can be solved using Views there is an easier way.

### Use Content view modes to control ER Field display

The easiest way to control which Fields from the referenced node an Entity reference Field should display is to use Content type Fields **view modes** (not related to Views module).

You can see available view modes on the `Manage display` page of a Content type, at the bottom under `Custom display settings`.

You need to enable an existing view mode or create a new one on your `Product` and `Purchase` Content types, so they can be used for ER Field on Sales CT.

Select the view mode you want to use (Manage display page) for this purpose and on `Product` CT hide all the Fields except the `product name`.

Similarly, on the `Purchase` CT view mode you selected for this purpose hide all the Fields except `MRP`.

Then on `Sales` CT Manage display page (I'm assuming you have two different ER Fields, one for each CT referenced) select **Rendered entity** as your ER Field Format for both Fields, and change its configuration to use the view mode you configured in previous steps.

This way when you visit a Sales node it will show `product name` and `MRP` Fields from the referenced nodes instead of their node titles.

### Create new Content view modes in D7

You might need to create a new view mode for this purpose. In D7 it doesn't come out of the box (as it does in D8), but you can create new modes with the help of an additional module or a very simple custom module. Read all about it in this article: [3 Easy Ways to Create View Modes in Drupal 7](https://www.webwash.net/3-easy-ways-to-create-view-modes-in-drupal-7/).

### Display information from another node

To display one node information on a different page (in your case you want to display MRP field from a Purchase node on Service pages) you can use Views module (this is different from view modes mentioned above).

You use Views to create a Block Display, filter out the node you need, and show only the MRP Field. The place that Block in a region in your theme (maybe Content region) and configure it so it shows only on Service CT nodes.

1. Create a new View of showing `Content` of type `All`, `Create a Block` of `fields`, showing `0` item (this means unlimited, for performance reasons)
2. Add a new Filter `Content: Nid`, keep the Operator `Is equal to` and enter your Purchase node ID number in the `Value` field (you can see the NID number on that node Edit page in the link)

   If you have Views preview enabled you can now see that exact Purchase node title in the Preview results
3. Rearrange the Filters so that `Content: Nid` Filter is above the `Content: Published (Yes)` Filter (this is for performance reasons)
4. Remove the `Content: Title` from Fields
5. Add a new Field `Content: MRP` (or whatever that field is called in your case), configure how you want that Field to appear on Service nodes
6. Save the View and place your Block in a region of your theme, but limit it to show only on `Service` CT

To test it visit one Service node and see if the Purchase MRP is showing there, and if you visit any other page then it shouldn't show.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the brief explanation. However, I have only one ER(Product Name) in Sales and with that ER I want to fetch MRP and Rate from purchase CT.

Comment: You can't fetch something that isn't in any way connected. Your Purchase doesn't seem to be connected to anything. Is there any type of link (ER or something else) between Purchase nodes and Sales or Product?

Comment: Only Product CT and Sales CT are connected using ER (Product name). Purchase CT and Sales CT are not connected in any way and I don't want to connect either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with Purchase nodes information, do you want to display _all_ Purchase nodes "MRP" on Sales?

Comment: I want to calculate amount using MRP(Maximum Retail Price) and Rate in Sales Content Type. So just want to fetch MRP and Rate from Purchase Content Type.

Comment: Will it always be from only one specific node of Purchase CT?

Comment: Yes. It will always be from Purchase CT.

Comment: Only one Purchase node or from many Purchase nodes?

Comment: Only one purchase node

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the steps on how to display one Purchase node MRP on all Service nodes.